# Linking a website or domain with AKS cluster

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

In Azure Kubernetes, the services or load balancer exposes IP Address to access a container's app. If one of the container has a web application, then it will be externally exposed as an IP like 115.111.0.145. Suppose I have a website [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) purchased from GoDaddy, then how can I link this domain with AKS cluster, so that the end user will be accessing the website by name and not IP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Ingress. Ingress is an API object that manages external access to the services in a cluster, typically HTTP. An Ingress may be configured to give Services externally-reachable URLs, load balance traffic, terminate SSL / TLS, and offer name-based virtual hosting. You can see the offical kubernetes [Ingress-doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) for more details.

Here as an example a simple yaml manifest of ingress is given:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: simple-fanout-example
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /foo
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port:
              number: 4200
      - path: /bar
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: service2
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Comment: Note that you'll still need to update DNS records to point towards the ingress controller external IP.

Comment: I agree with Sahadat Hossain, creating `Ingress` is a good approach.
For `Azure AKS` detailed instructions can be found here: [create-an-ingress-controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-static-ip#create-an-ingress-controller)

Comment: Thank you @Sahadat for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the DNS zone serivce of Microsoft azure in this case and can defines the set of canonical names for your site like -

1. **example.com** can be tagged to 'A' type record i.e. the IP of your Nginx controller's service exposed to load balancer.
2. Then you can create the multiple canonical names like -
   **api.example.com** and can map this to example.com as a CNAME type record in DNS zone.

This helps you direct the traffic from multiple domains to the cluster.

`kubectl get svc` shall give you the external IP for the nginx service and you can give that external IP in the A record of DNS zone.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Thank you @Tushar for the guidance.